# What does the + mean in software versioning

Tags: versioning

In libraries or packages I often see something like 0.5.4+6 or maybe 1.12.4+2, etc. I know the first number is the major version, the next one minor version, the next one maybe build number or revision. But what does the +2 or +6 signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it is used to provide some metadata / build metadata (eg. a build number or date).

For more detailed info, see the [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/#spec-item-10) spec.

Comment: I see thanks. And I know they could update the documentation as well, and that would be a +

Answer (score 0):

Trailing part after `MAYOR.MINOR.PATCH` not defined strictly in SemVer (AFAICR), thus - everybody can add *any useful* information in it. Most common usage - provide (in case of using VCS) unique (but readable) id, which allow to identify exact changeset in source, used for building *this* artifact.

Because (mainly) tags (or equivalent) used for naming|numbering versions in VCSes and (internal) builds between tags (releases) are possible, such ids appear, which, in plain words, mean something "N commits after version X".

Sample from my labeling (don't try to grok hg-templating, I'll explain it)

```
semver = "{latesttag}{ifeq(latesttagdistance,0,'','+{latesttagdistance}')}"
```

- Find latest tag in history
- If there are commits after it - add "+" sign and this number of commits

Just human-friendly type of id, which also allow (rather) fast detection of commit in question, if it's needed. And it's a lot more readable and memorable and pronounceable than, f.e. `b800644fcbe2`

Comment: Okay, what I get from this is that the plus means number of commits added to that version right?

Comment: @Philip - almost yes. In common "added commits" can be more, than *between* version and *this* changeset (think about parallel branches)